# Environment variable with newlines in PassEnvironment

Tags: systemd

I wrote a systemd unit that starts an executable script using PassEnvironment to pass a set of environment variables to the script. One of these variables is a certificate read from a file which has newlines, and it's not passed at all to the script: printing it I get no content. If i remove the newlines then the variable is passed correctly.

I cannot figure out another way to pass the variable to the script: everything runs inside a docker container, which I start defining the value for the environment variable containing the certificate, which is the passed to systemd that is the container process, which in turn passes it to the script. I cannot mount the certificate file as a docker secret since everything will run in a Gitlab CI so I can use only env variables for passing secrets. And I also cannot place the certificate in the image for security reasons.

So how can I make systemd coreectly pass my env variables with newlines to the script? I'm using systemd 219 in a CentOS container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd deliberately rejects "control" characters in environment variable values, which includes newlines. (I think the restrictions might have been *slightly* relaxed in later versions, but that doesn't help your v219.)

Convert the secret into a different format, e.g. Base64-encode the file into a single line – then have the container's script Base64-decode it before passing on to the application.

Comment: That's an extra step for setting up the container launch, but it works, so I'm happy with this. Thank you!